# blank screen after loading Rasbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I recently bought the Pi 3; it came with an SD card. When I started the Pi it asked me which software I would like to install, and I chose Raspbian.

Once the install was done, I was asked which software I would like to install, When I clicked Raspbian, it showed the Pi logo then went blank and I couldn't access anything.

I have looked on the web and a problem I came across was one about a screensaver but this does not seem to be the case.

I don't even get an option to login.

I have a feeling it might be that there is not enough power going through the screen to display, if I open the media server I installed, it works, but Raspbian doesn't.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is (I am away from my pi, so I can’t experiment and try to create the issue and my laptop is low on battery), but I would reccoment re-flashing the SD card.
Tutorial: https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-with-noobs/copy-noobs-onto-an-sd-card
(You will need an sd to usb converter or a laptop with an sd card port, for the converter I recommend this one: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anker-Reader-RS-MMC-Support-Warranty/dp/B00LFIXC8I)

Answer (score 0):

Use a class 10 memory card. And flash it with the latest buster.